# Solving the ODE: $\frac{1}{r} \frac{d}{d r} \left( r \frac{d f}{d r} \right) + \left( a - b e^{r^2} \right) f = c+ d e^{- r^2} $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, laplace-transform, laplacian, stability-in-odes

I'm trying hard to solve this:

$$\frac{1}{r} \frac{d}{d r} \left( r \frac{d f}{d r} \right) + \left( a - b e^{r^2} \right) f = c+ d e^{- r^2} $$

where $r$ ranges between $0$ and $\infty$, $a$ and $b$ are positive constants, $c$ and $d$ may have either sign.

Any of you is able to handle this?

Comment: Do you have reason to believe it can be solved in closed form at all? Also, are you sure the first exponential is $e^{r^2}$ and not $e^{-r^2}$?

Comment: Or asymptotically, for large and small $r$.

Comment: Asymptotically it seems like it is probably routine...

Comment: You have more experience than me... Any tip?

Comment: Why is there Laplace transform in the tags? Where did you get this ODE from? Fluid dynamics/electrostatics (because of the Laplacian)? The more details you give the more likely someone will be able to help you. At first glance, it is unlikely that you will obtain a closed form solution.

Comment: I tried with Mathematica and it doesn't find any closed form. Maybe you could name some asymptotic technique that befits this equation?

Comment: It is possible to know where you take this from ? for me it like a general type of equation that might a whole theory to solve . was this a given exercise?

Comment: Yeah a weird electrostatic exercise.

Comment: let $u=r^2$ then the equation simplifies to
$$4uy''+4y'+(a-be^u)y=(c+de^{-u})$$
where $y=f(u)$. I think it is too broad for solving with four parameters!

Comment: There is a nice special case in  http://science.fire.ustc.edu.cn/download/download1/book%5Cmathematics%5CHandbook%20of%20Exact%20Solutions%20for%20Ordinary%20Differential%20EquationsSecond%20Edition%5Cc2972_fm.pdf#page=273, hope that it may relate.

Comment: Ah.. what page did you see that exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$\dfrac{1}{r}\dfrac{d}{dr}\left(r\dfrac{df}{dr}\right)+\left(a-be^{r^2}\right)f=c+de^{-r^2}$

$\dfrac{d^2f}{dr^2}+\dfrac{1}{r}\dfrac{df}{dr}+\left(a-be^{r^2}\right)f=c+de^{-r^2}$

Let $s=r^2$ ,

Then $\dfrac{df}{dr}=\dfrac{df}{ds}\dfrac{ds}{dr}=2r\dfrac{df}{ds}$

$\dfrac{d^2f}{dr^2}=\dfrac{d}{dr}\left(2r\dfrac{df}{ds}\right)=2r\dfrac{d}{dr}\left(\dfrac{df}{ds}\right)+2\dfrac{df}{ds}=2r\dfrac{d}{ds}\left(\dfrac{df}{ds}\right)\dfrac{ds}{dr}+2\dfrac{df}{ds}=2r\dfrac{d^2f}{ds^2}2r+2\dfrac{df}{ds}=4r^2\dfrac{d^2f}{ds^2}+2\dfrac{df}{ds}$

$\therefore4r^2\dfrac{d^2f}{ds^2}+2\dfrac{df}{ds}+2\dfrac{df}{ds}+\left(a-be^{r^2}\right)f=c+de^{-r^2}$

$4r^2\dfrac{d^2f}{ds^2}+4\dfrac{df}{ds}+\left(a-be^{r^2}\right)f=c+de^{-r^2}$

$4s\dfrac{d^2f}{ds^2}+4\dfrac{df}{ds}+(a-be^s)f=c+de^{-s}$

Let $f=e^{ks}g$ ,

Then $\dfrac{df}{ds}=e^{ks}\dfrac{dg}{ds}+ke^{ks}g$

$\dfrac{d^2f}{ds^2}=e^{ks}\dfrac{d^2g}{ds^2}+ke^{ks}\dfrac{dg}{ds}+ke^{ks}\dfrac{dg}{ds}+k^2e^{ks}g=e^{ks}\dfrac{d^2g}{ds^2}+2ke^{ks}\dfrac{dg}{ds}+k^2e^{ks}g$

$\therefore4s\left(e^{ks}\dfrac{d^2g}{ds^2}+2ke^{ks}\dfrac{dg}{ds}+k^2e^{ks}g\right)+4\left(e^{ks}\dfrac{dg}{ds}+ke^{ks}g\right)+(a-be^s)e^{ks}g=c+de^{-s}$

$4s\left(\dfrac{d^2g}{ds^2}+2k\dfrac{dg}{ds}+k^2g\right)+4\left(\dfrac{dg}{ds}+kg\right)+(a-be^s)g=ce^{-ks}+de^{-(k+1)s}$

$4s\dfrac{d^2g}{ds^2}+4(2ks+1)\dfrac{dg}{ds}+(4k^2s+a+4k-be^s)g=ce^{-ks}+de^{-(k+1)s}$

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure, why is your final formulation better than the initial one?